# Find a Controller by the Route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I have a route and I need to know a controller that would be used for it.

I know how to find a controller for the current route:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteAction();
```

But how can I do the same for other routes?

Answer (score 2):

Route Facade is the answer. It can return `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection` object.
and then you can get `Illuminate\Routing\Route` object by route name.
Every Route triggers multiple actions such as middleware and controller methods. So we need only the controller.

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route as RouteFacade;
    
    /*@var $route Illuminate\Routing\Route*/
    $name = 'admin.reports.my-report.get-filters'; // sample route name
    $route = RouteFacade::getRoutes()->getByName($name);
    $controllerAction = $route->action['controller'];
    $controller = explode('@', $controllerAction)[0];

    logger($controller);
```

P.S.

In cases like that - remember to make a unit test for this functionality to be sure it works as you upgrade your laravel.